# Issue while added the new package under existing Package: Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I added a new activity which is under following Package

Activities -> UserManagement -> Auth -> Login

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Now, I am trying to add a new Package which should be under Activities Package.
Here the problem is that I have no option to add a new Package under Activities because they are combined with dot.

Can you please suggest how could I add the new Package under Activities.

Comment: Did you try opening the file explorer where the package is and placing the required file in the Activities folder ? That should automatically reflect in the android studio

Comment: Is there any way to do that through android studio?

Comment: When you create a new java class, in the `Package`, change it to `com.example.pankajgarg.android.Activities` that should solve the problem

Comment: if you post it as an answer, I will accept it. I am sure it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file by performing a right click on the package shown and Create a new `Class file`.
In the window that opens up, once you type in the filename, there will be another textbox called `Package` where a specific package path will be shown. Edit that to the required package location where this file has to be created. This will automatically expand the tree structure shown in Android Studio.